# Erro na exibição do relatório (FastReport) em software Multi-Idiomas

Tags: delphi, fast-reports, internacionalização

Estou com o seguinte erro na exibição de um relatório feito em FastReport.

[image: Erro Relatório FastReport]

Este erro começou a ocorrer após fazer a Internacionalização do meu software utilizando os recursos nativos do Delphi XE7 (Project->Languages->Add), quando o software roda em linguagem nativa o relatório é apresentado normalmente, mas quando é escolhido qualquer idioma adicional, o software passa a exibir a mensagem de erro conforme a imagem.

Código para exibição do relatório:

```
frRelatorio.Clear;
frRelatorio.LoadFromFile(IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(GetCurrentDir) + 'frRelatorio.fr3');
frRelatorio.PrepareReport;
frRelatorio.ShowReport();
```

Código que faz a troca do idioma: (Necessário a unit reinit da embarcadeiro).

```
case cbIdioma.ItemIndex of
  0:
    lang := LANG_PORTUGUESE;
  1:
    lang := LANG_SPANISH;
end;
if LoadNewResourceModule(lang) <> 0 then
  ReinitializeForms;
```

Espero que estas informações sejam suficientes, se necessário posso montar um exemplo com o erro, se alguém puder me ajudar, já agradeço.

ADD Link para download de exemplo gerando o erro:
https://mega.co.nz/#!qNFRyLAQ!YGjFJGghABhjw7RVB_1mGqFlGSvnGGESgUBXnGzj9ws

Comment: Montei um exemplo bem simples demonstrando o erro.

https://mega.co.nz/#!qNFRyLAQ!YGjFJGghABhjw7RVB_1mGqFlGSvnGGESgUBXnGzj9ws

Comment: @QMechanic73 Me parece que o problema aqui é que o arquivo que define o formulário, *TfrxPreviewForm.RES*, não foi incluído na compilação porque a diretiva de inclusão dele, que geralmente fica logo antes das declarações de tipos no arquivo .PAS (neste caso, *TfrxPreviewForm.PAS*) não foi processada. Tem que descobrir por que esta diretiva não foi processada - talvez ela nem esteja lá ou tenha sido substituída por outra coisa durante uma alteração no projeto.

Comment: Este erro só acontece quando o idioma é alterado via código

case cbIdioma.ItemIndex of
  0:
    lang := LANG_PORTUGUESE;
  1:
    lang := LANG_SPANISH;
end;
if LoadNewResourceModule(lang) <> 0 then
  ReinitializeForms;

OU quando o idioma é definido em Project->Language->Set Active

Comment: @QMechanic73 Por enquanto parei a fase de tradução, vou dar uma refinada no software quando estiver tudo certo, vou criar um novo projeto para cada idioma, acredito que a Embarcadeiro possa corrigir isso um dia.

Comment: Beleza, então, fico no aguardo. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Aparentemente não parece haver nenhuma solução para esse erro que é gerado pela classe [`EResNotFound`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_EResNotFound.html), essa exceção é lançada quando um recuso especifico, como um formulário que não pode ser encontrado, um arquivo de formulário(`.dfm`), arquivo de recursos, etc.

Uma das alternativas que você pode utilizar para contornar o uso do [**Translation Manager**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Translation_Manager_in_the_IDE) do Delphi, é utilizar [`Resource Strings`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Declared_Constants#Resource_Strings). *Resource Strings* são armazenados como recursos e ligado ao executável/biblioteca de modo que esses recursos podem ser modificados sem recompilar o programa.

Para fazer isso funcionar no seu programa multi-linguagem, você pode criar uma nova Unit (vá em `File` → `New` → `Unit`) nesta Unit será colocada as mensagens traduzidas para cada idioma que for usar no programa. Veja um exemplo:

```
unit untTraducoes;

interface

resourcestring

// Mensagens em Inglês
EN_FORM_CAPTION          = 'My Program Example';
EN_BTN_INFO_CAPTION      = 'Information';
EN_BTN_CLOSE_CAPTION     = 'Close';
EN_MEMO_TEXT             = 'Some text here';

// Mensagens em Português
PT_FORM_CAPTION          = 'Meu Programa Exemplo';
PT_BTN_INFO_CAPTION      = 'Informação';
PT_BTN_CLOSE_CAPTION     = 'Fechar';
PT_MEMO_TEXT             = 'Algum texto aqui';

implementation

end.
```

Primeiramente defina as constantes abaixo como globais.

```
Const
LANG_PT = 'PT'; // Português
LANG_EN = 'EN'; // Inglês
LANGUAGE_CONFIG_NAME = 'appconfig.ini'; // Arquivo onde vai ser guardado o idioma escolhido
LANGUAGE_DEFAULT     = 'PT'; // Idioma padrão do programa
```

Agora você poderá criar um método que verificará qual o idioma escolhido pelo usuário e aplicar as mensagens traduzidas aos componentes desejáveis.

```
procedure ApplyLanguage(Lang: string);
begin
If Length(Lang) = 0 then Exit; // Verifica o comprimento da string

If Lang = LANG_PT then begin   // Se for o idioma escolhido, então faça
  self.Caption := PT_FORM_CAPTION;
  self.BtnInfo.Caption := PT_BTN_INFO_CAPTION;
  self.BtnClose.Caption := PT_BTN_CLOSE_CAPTION;
  Self.Memo1.Text := PT_MEMO_TEXT;

end else if Lang = LANG_EN then begin
  self.Caption := EN_FORM_CAPTION;
  self.BtnInfo.Caption := EN_BTN_INFO_CAPTION;
  self.BtnClose.Caption := EN_BTN_CLOSE_CAPTION;
  Self.Memo1.Lines.Text := EN_MEMO_TEXT;    
end;

Application.ProcessMessages;
end;
```

Se você precisar salvar o idioma escolhido pelo usuário, poderá salva-lo em um arquivo que guarda configurações(extensão `.ini`), e manipular esse arquivo utilizando as funções da Unit [`IniFiles`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.IniFiles.TIniFile). Veja o método abaixo:

```
// Lembre-se de colocar a unit IniFiles em Uses
procedure ChangeLanguage(Lang: string);
Var
 Ini: TIniFile;
begin
if Length(Lang) = 0 then exit;
Try
  Ini := TIniFile.Create(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + LANGUAGE_CONFIG_NAME);
  Ini.WriteString('Opcoes', 'Lang', Lang);
  ApplyLanguage(Lang);
Finally
  Ini.Free;
End;
end;
```

Agora para dar a possibilidade de escolha de idioma ao usuário, coloque o código abaixo no evento [`OnSelect()`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/StdCtrls_TCustomCombo_OnSelect.html) do `ComboBox`:

```
Var
 Lang: string;
begin
Case cbIdioma.ItemIndex Of
    0: Lang := LANG_PT; // Português 
    1: Lang := LANG_EN; // Inglês
else Lang := LANG_PT;
End;

ChangeLanguage(Lang);
```

Por fim criaremos o método responsável por verificar qual o idioma será usado ao inicializar o programa.

```
// Lembre-se de colocar a unit IniFiles em Uses
procedure CheckDefaultLanguage;
Var
 Ini: TIniFile;
 LangOption: string;
begin
Try
  // Cria o .ini no Diretório do executável
  Ini := TIniFile.Create(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + LANGUAGE_CONFIG_NAME); 
  if Ini.SectionExists('Opcoes') = False then 
  // Se o arquivo ou seção não existir executa a linha abaixo e define o idioma padrão no arquivo
       Ini.WriteString('Opcoes', 'Lang', LANGUAGE_DEFAULT);

  // Lê o idioma definido no arquivo se não conseguir, devolve o idioma padrão
  LangOption := Ini.ReadString('Opcoes', 'Lang', LANGUAGE_DEFAULT);
  ApplyLanguage(LangOption); // Aplica o idioma escolhido
Finally
  Ini.Free; // Liberamos a instância
End;
end;
```

No evento `OnCreate()` do formulário chame o método `CheckDefaultLanguage`.

---

Você pode fazer algumas melhorias de acordo com a sua necessidade, um exemplo, verificar se um idioma está disponível antes de chamar o método `ApplyLanguage`.

Algumas imagens:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O exemplo(*baseado no seu exemplo*) pode ser baixado [**aqui**](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=05280533437846047149)(TinyUpload) - feito no Delphi XE3.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, espero que a Embarcadeiro melhore esse recurso nativo de multi-idiomas. Abraço.